# How do I get the value of the first child element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of the first child element from my HTML to show whenever I click on an image aka my 'services-cell" container, but it keeps saying the value is undefined.

```
    <div class="services-cell">
        <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
let galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.services-cell')


if(galleryImages) {
galleryImages.forEach(function(image){
    image.onclick = function() {
        console.log(galleryImages.firstElementChild.value)
    }
})
}
```

I tried to add the img class as a variable as well, but it also says undefined. I want the console.log to print

```
 <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="">
```

I have multiple images with the same html except it just say img-2, img-3 etc. So ideally whenever I click on the other images it would print the same HTML value but just will say the image number that I clicked on

Comment: `galleryImages` is an array like object.  You just looped over it.

Comment: so how would I go into it whenever I click on that container?

Comment: So for clarification, lets say you have 5 images on the page.  If you click on the 3rd one, what should log?  If you click on the 5th one, what should log?

Comment: wouldn't it simpler to target the images only `'.services-cell img'`, then the onclick will be the clicked image, then use console.log(this) or traverse

Answer (score 1):

You created the array as `galleryImages`, but then rather than accessing the `firstElementChild` of the `div`, you're trying to access that property on the array. You need to do `image.firstElementChild` instead. Also, as far as I know, accessing `.value` of an image has no meaning, I think you meant to just do `firstElementChild` instead:

```js
let galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.services-cell');

if (galleryImages) {
    galleryImages.forEach(function (image) {
        image.onclick = function() {
            console.log(image.firstElementChild);
        };
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="services-cell">
  <img class="services-cell_img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/deciduous-tree.png" alt="">
  <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
</div>
<div class="services-cell">
  <img class="services-cell_img" src="https://cdn-cloudfront.cfauthx.com/binaries/content/gallery/gg-en-us/icons/gg-tree-icon.png" alt="">
  <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah okay this is showing the value now thanks! I'm creating an image gallery, so would it matter if I target just the img html or would I need to only target the src link when I'm selecting images through Javascript?

Comment: @Brian no problem, and what do you mean by targeting the html vs the src link?

Comment: @Brian do you mean whether you `console.log` the entire html of the image vs just the `src` attribute?

Comment: yeah so if I am on my website and I have 10 images for example, then I click on image 1 and I wanted that image to pop up full width on the screen, would it matter on my javascript if I am targeting the entire img html or would the image still pop up when I click on it if I only targeted the src="image-1" part? 

Or does that not matter?

Comment: @Brian I haven't really tried something like that before but my best guess would be to use the reference to the image (aka create a variable referencing `image.firstElementChild`) and then change its `style` property to increase the width or apply whichever other style change you wanted

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to achieve this is passing the event attribute as a parameter of the onclick function.
The event attribute has a target; which is the item that triggered the event. So for example:

```
if(galleryImages) {
galleryImages.forEach(function(image){
    image.onclick = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.firstElementChild.value)
    }
})
}
```

However instead of adding an eventListener to every element, it might be better to add one event handler on the parent - and check which item is clicked.
E.g.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="services-cell">
        <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-cell">
        <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
 document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.matches('.services-cell'){
        // Do  something with the e.target - which is the .services.cell
    }
}
```